# PDF highlight appears below text rather than exactly over the text

Tags: pdf

If I highlight the text in a text based PDF (not a scanned one), the highlight appears below the text rather than exactly over the text.

I could also verify that there is a constant difference in coordinates between the text and a rectangular annotation drawn around it by using PDFBox and Java.

Will be happy to hear from anybody who knows why. Thanks.

Comment: What application are you using to view PDF's?

Comment: @nmenego Good question, pity I missed it. I had seen this in Adobe Reader 11.0.4. After you asked, I tried PDF Xchange Viewer 2.5 and the problem didn't occur. Not sure if Adobe Reader has an issue, or if PDF Xchange Viewer absorbs any possible mistake in the PDF.